# Runtime error 9 when trying to rename sheets using two cell values

Tags: excel, vba

Am trying to rename all sheets in workbook with combination of two cell values(Cell A1 and A2). But i am getting run time error '9' Subscription out of range.

My code is as follows:

```
Sub my()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets

ws.Name = ws.Range("A1").Value & "~" & Split(Range("A2").Value, " ")(0)
Next

End Sub
```

where,value of cell A1 is "a" and value of cell A2 is "00   b"

Please help.Thanks.

Comment: You take the first part of the name from the worksheet you are renaming.  You take the second part from the active worksheet.  I would add `Debug.Print ws.Range("A1").Value` and `Debug.Print Split(Range("A2").Value, " ")(0)` before the the rename so I could see which part of the expression was giving the error.

Comment: Split(Range("A2").Value, " ")(0) is giving error , but don't know why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you haven't set the `Worksheet` of the second `Range` object, so it's accessing the value from your active sheet instead of `ws`. The error 9 will occur either if "A2" is blank or if you are trying to assign a duplicate name. My bet is you had a different worksheet activated and that had a blank cell "A2".

Your line could be:

```
ws.Name = ws.Range("A1").Value & "~" & Split(ws.Range("A2").Value, " ")(0)
```

But I would heed Tony Dallimore's advice if I were you as there's no handling of any errors in your code. Try assigning the first and second parts to variables and test that they are okay before renaming your sheet.

FWIW, I'd also define the parent of the `Worksheets` object, like so:

```
For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
```

Comment: When i modified as ws.Name = ws.Range("A1").Value & "~" & Split(ws.Range("A2").Value, " ")(0) , and For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ,there is same error again.

Comment: See my modified response, and assign the `Worksheets` parent too, as edited above.

Comment: Then you either have duplicate names or no value in cell "A2". Have you written the error handling code yet, as suggested?

Comment: After adding Worksheets parent same error is coming.

Comment: Hi Ambie .....Many many thanks....error is solved now after adding ThisWorkbook.Worksheets...Again thanks a lot .....